# What does MT and MD stand for?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to wrap my head around how MT and MD options are used when compiling C/C++ projects. However, without being able to expand these supposed abbreviations to meaningful phrases, I forget which one is which from one paragraph to the next.  Strangely enough none of the text I've read starts by defining the M, the T and the D. What do they stand for?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2019

Comment: `MultiThreaded` and `MultiThreadedDebug`.

Comment: I've already read the text on this link and it doesn't answer the question. It says how the different options are used bu not what the abbreviation stand for.

Comment: MT makes sense for MultiThreaded but MTd seems to be used for MultiThreadDebug. So what is MD? MultiDreaded?

Comment: @Eneroth3, The full text of the abbreviations is certainly in there: Mutlithreaded and Multithreaded DLL.

Comment: If you know what these switches are used for, then what exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is what the abbreviation stand for, not what the options do.

Comment: These are acronyms, not *abbreviations*. They aren't required to actually stand for anything, grammatically speaking.

Comment: A long long time ago there was a version of CRT that was not Multithreaded.  Option /ML.  So the M definitely does not mean Multithreaded.  This all happened way too long ago, whomever made the choice is sipping pina-coladas on a sunny beach today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**D**LL and in**t**ernal may be used as mnemonic to distinguish /MD from /MT.

Answer (score 4):

These switches for `cl.exe` specify which C runtime library to link against; `/MT` specifies to link with `LIBCMT.LIB`; `/MD` specifies to link with `MSVCRT.LIB`.

The different CRT libraries are described in greater detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=vs-2019). The primary difference between `LIBCMT` and `MSVCRT` is that the former links the CRT statically into your output file, whereas `MSVCRT` links to the VC runtime DLL (which, unlike its name suggests, is not `MSVCRT.DLL` (see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273))).

Answer (score 4):

From the compiler options link given by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) above:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2019

```
/MD    Creates a multithreaded DLL using MSVCRT.lib.
/MDd   Creates a debug multithreaded DLL using MSVCRTD.lib.
/MT    Creates a multithreaded executable file using LIBCMT.lib.
/MTd   Creates a debug multithreaded executable file using LIBCMTD.lib.
```

Thus MT stands for **M**ulti**t**hreaded and MD stands for **M**ultithreaded **D**LL.

Comment: If MT means for MulthiThreaded I'd expect MultThreaded Dll to be written as MDT. That or simply M for Multithreaed.

But thanks for actually answering the question!

Comment: Not correct. `/LD` creates DLL and `/LDd` creates debug DLL. `/MD` links runtime dynamically, while `/MT` links it statically.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer are you arguing with Microsoft's own documentation, whose text I simply copied and pasted? /LD creates a single threaded DLL, not a multithreaded one

Comment: @RobK Just noting that the [current Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170) agrees with @ScienceDiscoverer. E.g. that `/MD` "[c]auses the application to use the multithread-specific and DLL-specific version of the run-time library" and that `/MT` "[c]auses the application to use the multithread, static version of the run-time library". Not sure why the one-line summaries in the page you linked are written as such; they're quite misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I also searched this for my question, and here are more detailed explanations by [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170):

**MSVC compiler options**

(emphasis mine)

> **/MD**   Causes the application to use the multithread-specific and
> **DLL-specific version of the run-time library.** Defines _MT and _DLL and
> causes the compiler to place the library name MSVCRT.lib into the .obj
> file.
>
> Applications compiled with this option are statically linked to
> MSVCRT.lib. This library provides a layer of code that enables the
> linker to resolve external references. The **actual** working code is
> contained in MSVCRversionnumber.DLL, which must be **available at run
> time** to applications linked with MSVCRT.lib.

> **/MDd** Defines _DEBUG, _MT, and _DLL and causes the application to use
> the debug multithread-specific and DLL-specific version of the
> run-time library. It also causes the compiler to place the library
> name MSVCRTD.lib into the .obj file.

> **/MT**   Causes the application to use the multithread, **static version of
> the run-time library.** Defines _MT and causes the compiler to place the
> library name LIBCMT.lib into the .obj file so that the linker will use
> LIBCMT.lib to resolve external symbols.

> **/MTd**  Defines _DEBUG and _MT. This option also causes the compiler to
> place the library name LIBCMTD.lib into the .obj file so that the
> linker will use LIBCMTD.lib to resolve external symbols.

The page also explains other compiler options /LD and /LDd, which are used when creating DLLs.